# Can a question with an open bounty on it be migrated from M.SE to MO?

Tags: discussion, bounty, migration

- Can a question with an open bounty on it be migrated from M.SE to MO?
- What happens with a bounty in this case?
- Can the bounty be awarded to an answer of a user who does not have a linked account at MO?
- Who can award the bounty if the user who started the bounty does not have a linked account at MO?

Comment: See also [What happens to a bounty question if it gets migrated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38819/what-happens-to-a-bounty-question-if-it-gets-migrated) on meta.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No and yes.  Questions with open bounties cannot be closed for any reason, and this includes migration.  In order for a question with a bounty to be migrated, the bounty would first have to be removed.  Moderators *can* remove bounties (and refund the reputation in the process), but we only do this on a case-by-case basis.  (See the [MSO FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/214632).)